# Files lost after Reinstalling Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: installation, 13.10, reinstalling

I had problmes with 13.10, and i reinstalled it with option "All documents, data, sofware will be saved".

But after reinstalling i saw that some apps are lost (Chromium, Chrome, Dropbox, Apache, Mysql etc.)

And with apache all my files are lost. There's no /var/www/ folder anymore.

All my works were in that folder. Is it possible to recover them?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. It sounds like you used a Live USB/CD to reinstall. That's pretty nuclear, so recovering your files would be extremely difficult.

Sorry.